# Full width child divs, multiple times down the page

Tags: css, html, width

So I have a design and it has multiple 100% browser width images down the page. I tried creating a few divs down the page and setting them to absolute position (even though the parent and following child were set to relative) but the text is floating behind the image.

I've tried a few other things and tried searching for an answer on here (without using jQuery) but I just wanted some more clear insight into how best to approach this. I have attached an image sample below:

[image: Sample]

The closest examples I can find usually only have 1 image at the very top of the page.

Comment: This is very confusing. Can you explain what you mean? Is the grey part 3 different boxes or is it all one box?

Comment: Sorry the grey box would be 1 tall div then the inner black boxes would be child divs within the grey one but they would span 100% of the window.

Comment: @lemdon what is the problem?  Can you show us what you've trieD?

Comment: I am pretty sure this isn't possible with CSS. Maybe jQuery